# Error to display Arabic data with PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, arabic

Does someone have an idea please?
My problem is that the result that my query SQL which is in Arabic is displayed with characters like that Ø¹Ù "ÙŠÙ ‡ Ø§Ù".
While I do all:

- for my database : cp1256_general_ci
- column of table : utf_bin8
- connect to data base :

```
// CONNEXION BDD
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jeu', 'root', '', array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
));


<?php
    require_once('inc/init.inc.php');
    $req= $pdo -> query("select * from proposition ");
    while($data=$req -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       echo' <form action="" method="post">';
       echo $data['question'].'<br />';
       echo $data['id_propo'].'<br />';
       echo '<input type="radio" name="rep" value='.$data["rep1"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].' />'.$data['rep1'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" value='.$data["rep2"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].' />'.$data['rep2'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" value='.$data["rep3"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].' />'.$data['rep3'].'<br />';
    echo    '<input type="radio" name="rep" value='.$data["rep4"].'+'.$data['id_propo'].' />'.$data['rep4'].'<br /><br />';
       }

 echo '</form>';

?>
```

Comment: Can't say anything about cp1256_general_ci/utf_bin8, but you should also check your HTTP headers, php.ini contains "default_charset" variable that may break what you see in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your database to utf8mb4_general_ci type instead of utf8. This is the best choice for you i think. Also check that you have applied a html header:

```
<meta charset=”utf-8”>
```

Comment: HTML tag is not necessary when HTTP headers contain the proper encoding.

Comment: Also check that you have correct encoding in your database tables.

Comment: Of course but practice shows that its better to add the html header.